# Using object as as a parameter of get method of Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use array as a parameter of get method of Angular.
I use codes like below.

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http'; 
constructor(private http: Http) {}
this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/test',{
 params: {user}
})
```

user is defined as `{id: number=101, name: string='john'}`

and I expect to generate URL

http://localhost:5000/test?id=101&name=john

However, generated URL is

http://localhost:5000/test?user=%7B%id%22:%22YV1AMbiy%22,%22name%22:%22345678%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove {} from params definition of get method

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http'; 
constructor(private http: Http) {}
this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/test', params: user )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
let params = new HttpParams()
    .set('id', 101)
    .set('name','john');

 return this._HttpClient.get(URL, { params: params })
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing  `params: {user}` it should be `params: user`. Otherwise, it will be transpiled as `params: { 'user': user }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify` in Angular

```
this.http.get(
    `http://localhost:5000/test`,
    {
        params: { user: JSON.stringify(user) },
    },
);
```

And in your backend you can use:

```
const user = JSON.parse(req.query.user)
```