# How to read a param value correct

Tags: angular, object, url, query-string

I'm trying to send an object from one page to the rerouted page using angular. I have found similar topics around this which I have tried to reproduce but I still get undefined value. Although I seem to do it right according to this topics.

- [How to pass Objects between pages in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70383159/how-to-pass-objects-between-pages-in-angular)
- [Get route query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488568/get-route-query-params)
- [Using object as as a parameter of get method of Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52802793/using-object-as-as-a-parameter-of-get-method-of-angular)
- https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/get-query-parameters-in-angular/

```
  goToOrderPage(){

 //code to create object

    let order = new Order("BTWNummer", "mail", this.totalPrice, this.sendCosts, orderlineset)

    console.log(
      "before send" + 
      order.btw + " - " + order.totalPrice + " - " + order.shippingcost + " - " + order.email
      );

      this.router.navigate(["/orderinfo"], { queryParams:  order });
  }
```

the object logs well and I have no error sending it. I get rerouted to the next page "/orderinfo":

```
export class OrderinfoComponent implements OnInit {
  order!:Order;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params=> {
      console.log(params);
      this.order = params['order'];
    
      console.log(
        this.order.btw + " - " + this.order.totalPrice + " - " + this.order.shippingcost + " - " + this.order.email
        );
    })
  }

}
```

Here do get an undefined value whilst logging the code. The console.log giving the queryparam does clearly log {order: Object object} I tried some other things to besides the code written down here, but I cannot get the value parsed. How do I properly parse to param value in the order object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just pass an entire object as a query parameter. You need to *encode* it somehow, because query string parameters are represented as... strings. You can either send every order property as a separate query string parameter, or look into other, more ergonomic ways of achieving the desired result. For example you can use [navigation extras `state`](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)

```js
this.router.navigate(["/orderinfo"], { state: order });
```

Then in your `OrderinfoComponent` you can access it *before the navigation ends* (usually in the component's constructor) like this:

```js
this.order = router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras.state as Order;
```

It is accessible also *after the navigation ends* by using `history.state`.

You can also include a service for holding the state that you want to share between certain components.

Comment: Is router still a part from ActivatedRoute? I get an error on it.

Comment: No, it's the `router: Router` the, actual Router.

Comment: I cannot get the code to compile. Or router gives error, unless I make it this.router, but than order gets error Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Order'

Comment: I mentioned in the answer that the `router.getCurrentNavigation` thing should happen inside the constructor. It should work without `this` there. Make sure this is written in the constructor. The `undefined` error is just a compiler error and I added a *fix* for it in the answer, please refresh the page.